Ubuntu 24.10 stopped working on W510 (Geforce FX880M)
I upgraded from 24.04 to Ubuntu 24.10, and it stopped working on ThinkPad W510 (GeForce FX880M). I checked also on USB installer. It's a problem with nouveau. The screen is black when GDM started, can login on blind, but the screen is still black. Is it the end of Ubuntu on old devices?

After turning off nouveau with nouveau.modeset=0 the screen shows the image, of course with a low resolution. Is there any way to fix nouveau? I tried load old kernel 6.8, but it's not working either.

Q: I am with same problem. I upgrade from 24.04 to 24.10. After upgrade a black screen appears instead the login screen. I not find a solution yet.
A: I was able to solve the problem. I edited the file /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and I removed the comment "#" of the line "WaylandEnable=false". There is a problem between Wayland and Nvidia. I had to change this options to work. Now I am waiting for an Ubuntu upgrade in orderto solve the problem definitively.
